# Python+PyQt4, QGraphicsScene too small

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qgraphicsscene

i want to create a `QGraphicsScene` and show it in a `QGraphicsView`. The problem is that my scene is a very small line (2mm-length) ) so i only see pixels in the QGraphicsView-Widget. Is there a way to change the size of the scene so it fits perfect in the GraphicsView-Widget(which has a static size).

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer:

```
self.graphicsView=QGraphicsView()
self.graphicsView.scale(100.0,100.0)
```

Now I can see small objects in my graphicsView.